# How to get locationchaged using Intentservice?

Tags: android, service, background, android-pendingintent, intentservice

I want to get Latitude and Longitude as and when location is changed.How it can be possible using Intentservice? other thing is that even application is in background I want current Latitude and Longitude continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try **getLastKnownLocation**(), but it is likely that it will be null. And an IntentService cannot wait around for some location fix to arrive.

Rather, you need a regular Service, crafted to handle this scenario. use [cwac-locpoll](https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll) instead

Comment: So u means that if I want continuous Location for that I have to use services not Intentservice?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement LocationListner in a service.  Here is a link that has more information.
[Location Listener in Background Service Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227446/location-listener-in-background-service-android)
and
[Location listener in a service sends notification issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390823/location-listener-in-a-service-sends-notification-issue)

In case you dont want to use a service:
[BroadcastReceiver for location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240246/broadcastreceiver-for-location)
You need to implement a custom broadcast receiver.

Comment: I don't want to use service because it drains battery.How can I get same result which as you suggest me using service,but I want same result using Intentservice.Is it possible to get same result as service gives?

Comment: Try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240246/broadcastreceiver-for-location

Answer (score 0):

if you really have to use a IntentService, you can implement a loop with an appropriate timeout. use onLocationChanged to change some values.
the loop can be testing this values every one second. if values change, exit loop, if timeout is reached exit loop.
The loop will keep the IntentService alive waiting for onLocationChanged to fire.

Comment: found a better way to do this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866415/intentservice-how-to-enqueue-correctly

Comment: I tried this answer but  onlocationchanged never is fired, but it does work if you do the same code in a frangment or activity, I believe you cant use this "trick" in IntentService.

Comment: @angel, get the location using a new thread then use thread.join(10000);

Comment: @angel, get the location using a new thread then use thread.join(10000); to join the current thread with the new one. create a call back method that will be used in the onlocationchanged to capture the current location attributes